# How to call a helper class magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to call a helper class in magento but stuck with an error message from magento.

The helper class is located at

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php

The class name is

```
class Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare extends Mage_Core_Helper_Url
```

I tried the below call

```
$helper=Mage::helper('catalog_product_compare');
```

Error message I got

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Product_Compare_Helper_Data' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs

How can i call this helper class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare');
```